# Не могу разобраться с положением объекта Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, загрузка, координаты, save

В общем, есть один объект (базовый fps-контроллер от первого лица) на маленькой карте. Я пытаюсь сохранить положение координат (XYZ), чтобы в будущем можно было сохраняться и загружаться с текущего места с которого вышел из игры или сохранился. Ну как во многих играх.

Как вытаскивать значения XYZ понял, как их сохранять вроде тоже. А вот как правильно загружать - нет...

Вроде бы значения загружаются, но неизвестно куда и значения объекта не меняются.

Единственное, при загрузке, на долю секунды будто переносит на эти самые координаты...

На скрине (желтым - текущие координаты; красным - сохранено\загружено)

Уже часа 4 мучаюсь... Буду очень благодарен за подсказку или разъяснение вопроса...
[image: transform]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    float PosX;
    float PosY;
    float PosZ;
    public Transform CurrentPlayerPosition;
    public GameObject player;

void Update () 
{
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        savePosition();
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L)) 
        loadPosition();

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        ResetData();
}

void savePosition()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter(); 
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath 
        + "/MySaveData.dat"); 
    SaveData data = new SaveData();

    Transform CurrentPlayerPosition = this.gameObject.transform;
    Debug.Log("SAVE" + CurrentPlayerPosition.position);

    data.PosX = CurrentPlayerPosition.position.x;
    data.PosY = CurrentPlayerPosition.position.y;
    data.PosZ = CurrentPlayerPosition.position.z;

    bf.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();
    Debug.Log("Game data saved!");
}

void loadPosition()
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath 
        + "/MySaveData.dat"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = 
        File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath 
        + "/MySaveData.dat", FileMode.Open);
        SaveData data = (SaveData)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();

        PosX = data.PosX;
        PosY = data.PosY;
        PosZ = data.PosZ;

        CurrentPlayerPosition.position = new Vector3(PosX, PosY, PosZ);

        player = GameObject.Find("Player").gameObject;
        player.transform.position = CurrentPlayerPosition.position;

        Debug.Log("LOAD" + CurrentPlayerPosition.position);
        Debug.Log("LOAD player" + player.transform.position);

        Debug.Log("Game data loaded!");
    }
    else
        Debug.LogError("There is no save data!");
}

void ResetData()
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath 
        + "/MySaveData.dat"))
    {
        File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath 
        + "/MySaveData.dat");
        PosX = 0.0f;
        PosY = 0.0f;
        PosZ = 0.0f;
        Debug.Log("Data reset complete!");
    }
    else
        Debug.LogError("No save data to delete.");
    }
}

[Serializable]
class SaveData
{
  public float PosX;
  public float PosY;
  public float PosZ;
}
```

Comment: Может у вас скрипт движения меняет координаты?

Comment: Возможно при старте либо при движении происходит смещение координат, в Debug.Log проверили данные? Всё корректно?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего проблема кроется в иерархии обьектов. В юнити есть локальная и глобальная системы координат.

Представим себе что твой плеер находится в мировой системе координат с положением x, y, z. Но в иерархии находится внутри другого обьекта и его координаты будут x1, y1, z1. И ты по незнанию обращаешся к последним. т.е. вполне возможен вариант что ты обращаешся к локальным координатам вместо глобальных.

Что до сохранять и загружать - я настоятельно советую использовать PlayerPrefs.